# Mysql Left Outer Join do not include all recs from left table

Tags: mysql, sql, outer-join

I have 2 tables:

The left `table1` just include ID and Status as text und just 5 Recs
The `table2` is linked by ID Table1 to an field which calls status in table2.

What I like to do is to sum the numbers of all types of status.
My Idea was to using an left outer join an get a list of all status with numbers behind. in Case there no linked recs from table2 to an status it should a `NULL` appears.

But my SQL statement just work like an ordinary join and bring only equal records. but not the records from table1 with NULL

I'd apreciate if you can have a look to my SQL statement:

```
SELECT task.tas_status
  ,v_task_status_1.param_str1
FROM v_task_status_1
LEFT OUTER JOIN task ON (v_task_status_1.param_id = task.tas_status)
```

Comment: Sum or count per status?

Comment: Please check whether your column names in ON are correct.

Comment: Have you swapped the left and rigth tables? For your description it lloks like they're exchanged.

Comment: Please show an example of what tables you've got, what result you obtain from your query and what result you would like to obtain instead. Personally, I'm not entirely sure you've got the left and right tables right, although that may well be because of inconsistency in your explanation: you are talking about `table1` and `table2` whereas your query references `v_task_status_1` and `task`, and I'm unsure which is which.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `COUNT()` function to count and then use `GROUP BY` as well

```
SELECT 
 t2.tas_status,
 COUNT(*) as CountPerStatus 
FROM v_task_status_1 t1
 LEFT OUTER JOIN task t2 
 ON t1.param_id = t2.tas_status
GROUP BY t2.tas_status
```